# Gekko : How to retrieve the result from an array variable and why it does not solve in local

Tags: python, gekko

I have two issues : One is not related to the solver but to how to retrieve my results, the other is related to the solver when I work in local

Also I could not find enough intel in the documentation but i was wondering what are the algorithms behind IMODE = 4 and 7 ?

The first issue is that I tried everything to retrieve the 100 values of dist for each time to put on an animation. I did not succeed and I do not understand why...

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc

# Temps de simulation
tf = 100
# Nombre de tranches d'âge et initialisation nb personne dans une tranche
N = 100
x = np.linspace(0, N, N)
y = 10 + 40 * np.exp(-30 * ((x/100) - 0.5)**2) + np.random.normal(0, 1, size=100)
y = (y - np.min(y)) / (np.max(y) - np.min(y)) * 20 + 10

# Nombre de pas de temps
Ndt = tf*1000
# Création de l'instance du modèle GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
# m.open_folder()
m.time = np.linspace(0, tf, Ndt)

# Données d'entrée
birth_rate  = 0.001  # taux de natalité
death_rate  = 0.0005  # taux de mortalité
growth_rate = 0.01  # taux de croissance 

# Variables du modèle
dist    = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
birth   = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
death   = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
growth  = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)

# Contraintes initiales
for i in range(N):
    dist[i].VALUE = y[i]

# Contraintes sur la variable dist

m.Equation([dist[i].dt() == - death[i] + growth[i-1]    for i in range(1,N)])
m.Equation([birth[i] == 0                               for i in range(1,N)])
m.Equation([death[i] == death_rate * dist[i]*i          for i in range(1,N)])
m.Equation([growth[i] == growth_rate * dist[i]          for i in range(1,N)])

m.Equation(dist[0].dt() == birth[0] - death[0])
m.Equation(birth[0] == birth_rate * dist[0])
m.Equation(death[0] == death_rate * dist[0])
m.Equation(growth[0] == 0)

# Résolution du modèle
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=True)

# Créer la figure et les axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ydata = np.zeros((N))

# Fonction qui met à jour l'animation
def update(frame):
    # Effacer le dessin précédent
    ax.clear()
    
    ydata[:] = np.array(dist[frame].VALUE)
    # Tracer la ligne
    ax.plot(np.arange(len(ydata)), ydata)

    # Définir les limites des axes
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(dist))
    ax.set_ylim(0, np.amax(ydata) )

    # Ajouter les étiquettes des axes
    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')

    # Ajouter un titre à la figure
    ax.set_title(f'Animation Example Temps: {frame*5}')

# Créer l'animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=Ndt, interval=10)

# Afficher l'animation
ani.save('distribution.gif')
plt.show()
```

Gives me the following error (I spare you all the iteration) :

```
Number of Iterations....: 72

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Dual infeasibility......:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Constraint violation....:   5.4521725359095381e-07    5.4521725359095381e-07
Complementarity.........:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Overall NLP error.......:   5.4521725359095381e-07    5.4521725359095381e-07


Number of objective function evaluations             = 107
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 39
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 563
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 73
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 72
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.146
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.212

EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is   0.000000000000000E+000

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :   0.397200000006706      sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\yaj\Downloads\Gekko_test.py", line 81, in <module>
    ani.save('distribution.gif')
  File "C:\Users\yaj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1068, in save
    anim._init_draw()  # Clear the initial frame
  File "C:\Users\yaj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1721, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(frame_data)
  File "C:\Users\yaj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1743, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "c:\Users\yaj\Downloads\Gekko_test.py", line 62, in update
    ydata[:] = np.array(dist[frame].VALUE)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (100,)
```

The second issue I have is when I work with :  `m = GEKKO(remote=False)`

Here the result :

```
PS C:\Users\yaj\Downloads\H0504-Kinetic Digital Modelling> conda activate base
PS C:\Users\yaj\Downloads\H0504-Kinetic Digital Modelling> & C:/Users/yaj/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/yaj/Downloads/Gekko_test.py
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  0
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  400
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  0
   Equations    :  400
   Residuals    :  400


Error: At line 1545 of file apm.f90
Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
Fortran runtime error: Out of memory

Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\yaj\Downloads\Gekko_test.py", line 50, in <module>
    m.solve(disp=True)
  File "C:\Users\yaj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2227, in solve
    self.load_JSON()
  File "C:\Users\yaj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_post_solve.py", line 13, in load_JSON
    f = open(os.path.join(self._path,'options.json'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\yaj\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpnfynca23gk_model0\\options.json'
```

I truly find Gekko amazing and I'm working on mastering it for my work !

Thank you for all you work and dedication !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMODE=4` is a simultaneous simulation where all `100000` time points and `4x100=400` states + `1x100` differentials are solved together. The problem size is `100000 x 5 x 100 = 50,000,000` variables and equations. It appears that there is a problem with transferring a time vector to the remote server that is `100000` lines long so it only calculates one time step. However, it doesn't have the same problem with transferring the time vector for a local solution so it attempts to create the large problem and runs out of memory. If it is a Windows computer, the local solver is 32-bit so the maximum that a process can allocate is 4 GB. On Linux and MacOS, it is a 64-bit local solver. However, a large memory allocation with 50M variables is not a good idea because it would take a while to solve with a nonlinear programming solver such as IPOPT. The problem appears to be linear so it should solve in a couple iterations. Switching to `IMODE=7` solves the differential equations one time step at a time. However, 100000 time steps will take a while to compute.

Stay with `IMODE=4` and reduce the number of time steps for simulation. Instead of computing 1000 time steps every year, try just one time step for each year as a starting point. APOPT solver finds the solution to 50000 variables and 50000 equations in 0.27 sec.

```
 Number of state variables:          50000
 Number of total equations: -        50000
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              0
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Simulation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  1.36282E-31  7.67439E-01
    1  1.36282E-31  7.67439E-01
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   0.270599999988917      sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the animation:

[image: animation]

with the source code:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc

# Temps de simulation
tf = 100
# Nombre de tranches d'âge et initialisation nb personne dans une tranche
N = 100
x = np.linspace(0, N, N)
y = 10 + 40 * np.exp(-30 * ((x/100) - 0.5)**2) + np.random.normal(0, 1, size=100)
y = (y - np.min(y)) / (np.max(y) - np.min(y)) * 20 + 10

# Nombre de pas de temps
Ndt = tf+1
# Création de l'instance du modèle GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
# m.open_folder()
m.time = np.linspace(0, tf, Ndt)

# Données d'entrée
birth_rate  = 0.001  # taux de natalité
death_rate  = 0.0005  # taux de mortalité
growth_rate = 0.01  # taux de croissance 

# Variables du modèle
dist    = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
birth   = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
death   = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)
growth  = m.Array(m.Var, N, lb=0)

# Contraintes initiales
for i in range(N):
    dist[i].VALUE = y[i]

# Contraintes sur la variable dist

m.Equations([dist[i].dt() == - death[i] + growth[i-1]    for i in range(1,N)])
m.Equations([birth[i] == 0                               for i in range(1,N)])
m.Equations([death[i] == death_rate * dist[i]*i          for i in range(1,N)])
m.Equations([growth[i] == growth_rate * dist[i]          for i in range(1,N)])

m.Equation(dist[0].dt() == birth[0] - death[0])
m.Equation(birth[0] == birth_rate * dist[0])
m.Equation(death[0] == death_rate * dist[0])
m.Equation(growth[0] == 0)

# Résolution du modèle
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)

# Créer la figure et les axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

# Fonction qui met à jour l'animation
def update(frame):
    # Effacer le dessin précédent
    ax.clear()
    
    ydata = dist[frame].VALUE
    # Tracer la ligne
    ax.plot(np.arange(len(ydata)), ydata)

    # Définir les limites des axes
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(dist))
    ax.set_ylim(0, np.amax(ydata) )

    # Ajouter les étiquettes des axes
    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')

    # Ajouter un titre à la figure
    ax.set_title(f'Animation Example Temps: {frame*5}')

# Créer l'animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=N, interval=10)

# Afficher l'animation
ani.save('distribution.gif')
plt.show()
```